# Set labels and colors (scale fill manual) based on a numeric variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
lvl.limit.low <- 0.5
lvl.limit.high <- 8.5
DF<-data.frame(ID=c(seq(1,10, by = 1)),
               flow.1=c(9.1,.6,9,9.2,9.1,0.6,0,4.3,9.1,0.3)) %>% 
  mutate (
    flow.lvl = case_when(
      flow.1 > 7 ~ lvl.limit.high,
      flow.1 > 4 ~ lvl.limit.low,
      flow.1 < 0.99 ~ lvl.limit.low-1,
      .default = 999
      )
)

ggplot (DF) +
  geom_col (aes (x = ID, y = flow.lvl, fill = factor(flow.lvl) )) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("-0.5" =  "red3", "0.5" = "orange3", "8.5" = "darkgreen"),
    labels = c("-0.5" = "0", "8.5" = "4", "0.5" = "1")
  )
```

This code works perfectly - gives the result as expected

When I make a change and in labels and values I want to use variables (`lvl.limit.low` , `lvl.limit.high`) I get an error message. I know it can't work because `factors` apply to the `fill` setting.

```
ggplot (DF) +
  geom_col (aes (x = ID, y = flow.lvl, fill = factor(flow.lvl) )) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("-0.5" =  "red3", "0.5" = "orange3", "8.5" = "darkgreen"),
    labels = c(lvl.limit.low-1 = "0", lvl.limit.high = "4", lvl.limit.low  = "1")
  )
```

The following works fine, however I would like a solution with an explicit association of a color to a value

```
ggplot (DF) +
  geom_col (aes (x = ID, y = flow.lvl, fill = factor(flow.lvl) )) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("red3", "orange3", "darkgreen"),
    labels = c("0", "4", "1")
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stats::setNames`:

```r
setNames(c("0", "4", "1"), c(lvl.limit.low-1, lvl.limit.high, lvl.limit.low))
# -0.5  8.5  0.5 
#  "0"  "4"  "1" 
dput(setNames(c("0", "4", "1"), c(lvl.limit.low-1, lvl.limit.high, lvl.limit.low)))
# c(`-0.5` = "0", `8.5` = "4", `0.5` = "1")

ggplot (DF) +
  geom_col (aes (x = ID, y = flow.lvl, fill = factor(flow.lvl) )) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("-0.5" =  "red3", "0.5" = "orange3", "8.5" = "darkgreen"),
    labels = setNames(c("0", "4", "1"), c(lvl.limit.low-1, lvl.limit.high, lvl.limit.low))
  )
```

[image: ggplot with named color literals]

(I should caution that doing this might cause corner-cases when floating-point math yields something like `0.50000000001`.)